# Cannot extract the data from the website using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a project which needs to get the data from other webpage:
https://eth.ethfans.org/#/miner?0x2998850087633a4806191960c94ed535d97da598

I am trying to use the function cRUL:

```
<?php

$url = "https://eth.ethfans.org/#/miner?0x2998850087633a4806191960c94ed535d97da598";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $contents;
?>
```

However, I can only get the layout of the site, but I cannot get the data inside.

Can anyone help for this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: try file_get_contents

Comment: thanks for your reply ... however... same result ><

Comment: You are downloading the page as html. You are looking for something called an API.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_get_html to fetch the data from the layout:

```
$get_html = str_get_html($contents);
```

Example:

```
function check()
  { 
    $url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248329/cannot-extract-the-data-from-the-website-using-php-curl";

    $get_html = $this->get_curl($url); 
    #print_r($get_html); exit;
    $get_html = str_get_html($get_html);

        $fb = NULL; 
        foreach ($get_html->find('a') as $v) { // you can get what data from the layout

          if(strpos($v->href, 'facebook'))
          {
            echo $fb = $v->href;
            echo "\n";
            break;
          } 
        }
      unset($get_html);

  }

public function get_curl($url)
  {
    ob_start();

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    $headers = [
       'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
       'Cache-Control: no-cache',                      
       'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',                       
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $response = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm please reffer this link

Answer (score 0):

you're hitting the wrong url, the page you're hitting only contains the layout and the javascript required to fetch the actual data, then the javascript fetch the data from https://eth.ethfans.org/api/page/miner?value=2998850087633a4806191960c94ed535d97da598 , so, do as the javascript does, and fetch that url.